# Running Method From Another Class In Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying out an AI experiment and I've written a lot of code in one class called Board.java, but when I try to instantiate it in another class and use its run() method, it doesn't run. Here's some code:

```
public void run(){
    System.out.println("??");
    while(!has_died()&&!has_won()&&time_left()){
        System.out.println("a");
        int[][] surroundings=check_surroundings();
        System.out.println("*");
        Entry[] thinking=search_memory(surroundings,1);
        System.out.println("!");
        double[] judgement=create_probability(thinking);
        System.out.println("?");
        System.out.println(choose_and_execute_move(judgement));
        System.out.println("A");
        moves++;
    }
    System.out.println("uh");
    log.to_memory();
}
```

The print statements are there so I know what steps the program gets stuck on in case I have to deal with any tricky loop business.

Here is my class where I instantiate a board:

```
static String mem_add="mem.txt";
static int[][] board={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4},
                      {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};
static Board practice_1=new Board(board,mem_add,20);
public static void main(String[] args){
    practice_1.run();
}
```

But I get no output, not even the ?? to show that run was used at all. What should I be doing to ensure that run() actually is called and executed?

EDIT:
Its running, but its acting like its in some infinite loop in that it is not terminating.

Comment: Is `Board` a Threaded Object by chance?

Comment: Make sure that all classes are properly compiled (so that it's not using some old version of the Board class.)

Comment: Probably not, I did not do anything special to it. I say probably because I am unfamiliar with the term, but after a Google search of it I think I would know if it was.

Comment: As far as I can tell, everything is running and compiled as the most recent save of itself

Comment: The next step might be a MCVE.

Comment: How do you execute your main code fron eclipse?

Comment: I'm clicking the green button, which has always worked before in similar scenarios.

Comment: My guess is you should change the method name from run() to something else...
because if it is like an infinite loop or something the class that contains the method may be a thread that is running (with your run()) continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Update: it's all working now, kind of an odd occurrence, perhaps something wrong with my IDE one person commented that perhaps the most recent version of Board was not compiled, but in any case thanks for the input, must have been a quirk